# Realitykit / ArKit make a collision only between 2 objects

Tags: swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I have a ball and a cylinder. When i tap on the ball it moves in forward position. When the ball hits the cylinder they collide and the cylinder moves and changes color. Thats working fine.

I have 2 problems:
When i start the app the cylinder is constantly colliding and changes color immediately, so even when the ball is not near it. It looks like its colliding with something else.

The second thing is, there will be more cylinders in the scene, how can i make a collision event only between 2 objects. Lets say there are 2 cylinders in the scene how can ik set a filter or group.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import FocusEntity
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {
    
    
    var body: some View {

            ARViewContainer()
            
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let view = ARView()

        let session = view.session
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = .horizontal
        session.run(config)

        let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        coachingOverlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        coachingOverlay.session = session
        coachingOverlay.goal = .horizontalPlane
        view.addSubview(coachingOverlay)

        context.coordinator.view = view
        session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap)))
        
        return view
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }



//coordinator class
class Coordinator: NSObject,ARSessionDelegate {
    
    weak var view: ARView?
    var focusEntity: FocusEntity?
    
    @Published var sceneIsPlaced:Bool = false //is de scene reeds geplaats na openen app
    @Published var subscriptions: [AnyCancellable] = []


    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let view = self.view else { return }
        self.focusEntity = FocusEntity(on: view, style: .classic(color: .yellow))
    }
    
    
    //na tap op het scherm, wat te doen -> creeer locatie en plaats het object
    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        
            guard let view = self.view, let focusEntity = self.focusEntity else { return }
            
            //tap location van de tap gesture
            let tapLocation =  recognizer.location(in: self.view)
     
            //Create Anchor
            let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        

            let importModel = try! Entity.load(named: "cilinder") //alle objects!
            importModel.position = focusEntity.position
            importModel.scale = SIMD3(repeating: 0.5)

        
            //The cylinder
            let kolomMiddleModel = importModel.findEntity(named: "cilinder")!.children[0] as! (ModelEntity & HasPhysicsBody & HasCollision)
            let materialKolomMiddle = SimpleMaterial(color: .yellow, isMetallic: true)
            kolomMiddleModel.model?.materials = [materialKolomMiddle]
            kolomMiddleModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            let physics = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .dynamic)
            kolomMiddleModel.components.set(physics)

            //MAKE A BALL
            let materialsBall = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: true)
            let ballModel = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1),
                                           materials: [materialsBall])
                                                               as (Entity & HasPhysicsBody & HasCollision)
                 
            ballModel.position = [-0.1, -1.0,-0.1]
            ballModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            ballModel.name = "ballModel"

            //LIGHTS --> let op voor de shadow moet de plane van occlusion material met dynamical lightning op tue
            let directionalLight = DirectionalLight()
            directionalLight.light.color = .white
            directionalLight.light.intensity = 4000
            directionalLight.light.isRealWorldProxy = true
            directionalLight.shadow?.maximumDistance = 1.5
            directionalLight.shadow?.depthBias = 7.0
            directionalLight.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/1.5, axis: [0,1,0])
            
            //maak een anchor voor het licht
            let lightAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0, 2.5])
            lightAnchor.addChild(directionalLight)
            
            
            //COLLISION EVENTS
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                //collision of kolomModel
                view.scene.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self,
                                     on: kolomMiddleModel) { _ in
                    print("Collision kolomModel detected!")
                    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: true)
                    kolomMiddleModel.model?.materials = [material]

                }.store(in: &self.subscriptions)
            }
            
            
//            view.installGestures(for: ballModel)
//
        
            //PLACE SCENE IF NOT PLACED ALREADY
            if !sceneIsPlaced {
                //ADD MODELS TO ANCHOR
             
                anchor.addChild(importModel)
                anchor.addChild(ballModel)
                anchor.addChild(lightAnchor)
                
                view.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
                sceneIsPlaced = true
                
            //If the scene is already placed get the taplocation
            }else{
                if let locationEntity = view.entity(at: tapLocation) {
                    let entityTapped = locationEntity as! ModelEntity
               
                    //MAKE THE BALL GO FORWARD
                    print("entity tapped \(entityTapped)")
                    entityTapped.physicsBody = .init()
                    entityTapped.physicsBody?.mode = .kinematic
                    entityTapped.physicsMotion = PhysicsMotionComponent(linearVelocity: [0, 0, -0.5],
                                                                       angularVelocity: [1, 3, 5])
 
                }
            }
        
    }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of two objects in RealityKit that can only collide with each other:

```swift
let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
sphere.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.1)])
sphere.collision?.filter = CollisionFilter(group: 1 << 2, categories: .default, mask: .default)

let cube = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
cube.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateBox(size: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])])
cube.collision?.filter = CollisionFilter(group: 1 << 1, categories: .default, mask: .default)

sphere.collision?.filter.collisionGroup = 1 << 1
cube.collision?.filter.collisionGroup = 1 << 2

arView.scene.addAnchor(sphere)
arView.scene.addAnchor(cube)
```

This code creates two objects: a sphere and a cube. Each object is given a CollisionComponent with a corresponding ShapeResource and CollisionFilter. The CollisionFilter for each object specifies that only objects in a different collisionGroup can collide with it. As a result, the sphere and cube can only collide with each other, not with other objects in the scene.

See more information about CollisionGroups here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/collisionfilter

Comment: tx, but in youre code the sphere and cube have a different filter group, am i right ? They are not colliding if its a different group. Maybe iam not understanding it right.

Comment: so let's call `1 << 1` the sphere's group and `1 << 2` the cube's group.
The collision filter on the sphere is set to `1 << 2` = the cube group.
The collision filter on the cube is set to `1 << 1` = the sphere group.

In this scenario: cubes can collide with spheres, and vice versa. But cubes cannot collide with other cubes, and spheres cannot collide with other spheres.

Comment: you might know this already, but for clarity, 1 << 1 and 1 << 2 are 0b10 and 0b100 collectively, so `0b10 AND 0b100` results in `0` -> no collision

Comment: collectively should be respectively in my last comment ‍♂️